# Excel VBA Password Prompt

Tags: passwords

I am creating a macro, whereby, the access is limited only to certain people.
In order to do this, I have created a password prompt.
The problem I am facing is that, when the user enters the password, it is being displayed.
What I want is that the machine should display XXX instead of digits typed. 
Is it possible ?

Comment: What control are you using for this?

Comment: From memory, if you set the `InputMask` property of a textbox to `Password` that will do it in a VBA textbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use some in-built function for it, i believe there is none. i would recommend you to create your own textbox prompting user to enter password and make it replace character typed by asterics or 'x'.
Another decision is to protect the file itself with password, which is an in-built feature.